# Cyotek ImageBox get zoomed part of image

Tags: c#, image

I am using Cyotek ImageBox to zoom a image, now if I zoom to a part of image and that part is visible in the ImageBox how can I save that part of image which is visible in ImageBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetSourceImageRegion` method allows you to get a `RectangleF` that describes the part of the image that is visible in the current state of an `ImageBox`.

The example code below will create a new `Bitmap` based on the visible part of the image. This example is not zoomed.

```
Rectangle visibleImageRegion;
Bitmap result;

visibleImageRegion = Rectangle.Round(imageBox.GetSourceImageRegion());
result = new Bitmap(visibleImageRegion.Width, visibleImageRegion.Height);

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
{
  g.DrawImage(imageBox.Image, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, visibleImageRegion.Size), visibleImageRegion, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

This next example does the same as above, but also scales the new image to match the `ImageBox`

```
RectangleF visibleImageRegion;
Bitmap result;
double zoomFactor;
int w;
int h;

visibleImageRegion = imageBox.GetSourceImageRegion();
zoomFactor = imageBox.ZoomFactor;

w = Convert.ToInt32(visibleImageRegion.Width * zoomFactor);
h = Convert.ToInt32(visibleImageRegion.Height * zoomFactor);
result = new Bitmap(w, h);

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
{
  g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
  g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

  g.DrawImage(imageBox.Image, new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h), visibleImageRegion, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

You could hook into the `Scroll` or `Zoomed` events of the control to detect when you need to update the image based on user activity.

Comment: how can I set the maximum and minimum zoom

Comment: Use the `ZoomLevelCollection` collection, accessed via the `ZoomLevels` property to set the increments - defaults are 7, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 50, 70, 100, 150, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 1200, 1600.

Comment: int[] zoomLevels = { 25, 75, 100 }; 

imageBox.ZoomLevels = new Cyotek.Windows.Forms.ZoomLevelCollection(zoomLevels);